# How to write a generic function in typescript with parameters of value or value[] for two parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a generic function which will take in a sting hasMapName and another parameter keys as string | string[] and a callback which will return T | T[].

if the key is string the callback should return T and if the key is String[] it should return back the T[].

Tried the following code:

```
    export function getData<K extends string | string[], T>(
      hashMapName: string,
      keys: K extends string[] ? string[] : string,
      serviceCallBack: K extends string[] ? () => Promise<T[]> : () => Promise<T>
    ): Promise<T> {
      return Array.isArray(keys)
        ? getDataForKeys<T>(hashMapName, keys, serviceCallBack)
        : getDataForKey<T>(hashMapName, keys, serviceCallBack);
    }
```

But I am getting an tserror at keys in getDataForKey.

Error:

```
Argument of type 'K extends string[] ? string[] : string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

**Update 1:**

Please find the declarations for the getDataForKeys and getDataForKey functions.

```
    declare function getDataForKey<T>(
      hashMapName: string,
      key: string,
      serviceCallBack: () => Promise<T>
    )

    declare function getDataForKeys<T>(
      hashMapName: string,
      key: string[],
      serviceCallBack: () => Promise<T[]>
    )
```

As we are strictly following the noExplicitAny policy, we won't be able to use any keyword for the functional parameters.

After trying the @Dmitriy answer, facing the following issue now.

```
Argument of type '(() => Promise<T[]>) | (() => Promise<T>)' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => Promise<T[]>'.
  Type '() => Promise<T>' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<T[]>'.
    Type 'Promise<T>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<T[]>'.
      Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T[]'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use overloaded functions instead of the conditional types for this usecase:

```js
declare function getDataForKey<T>(...args: any[]): Promise<T>;
declare function getDataForKeys<T>(...args: any[]): Promise<T[]>;


export function getData<T>(
  hashMapName: string,
  keys: string,
  serviceCallBack: () => Promise<T>
): Promise<T>
export function getData<T>(
  hashMapName: string,
  keys: string[],
  serviceCallBack: () => Promise<T[]>
): Promise<T[]>
export function getData<T>(
  hashMapName: string,
  keys: string | string[],
  serviceCallBack: (() => Promise<T[]>) | (() => Promise<T>)
): Promise<T> | Promise<T[]> {
  return Array.isArray(keys)
    ? getDataForKeys<T>(hashMapName, keys, serviceCallBack)
    : getDataForKey<T>(hashMapName, keys, serviceCallBack);
}

getData("foo", "fooo", async () => "bar"); // works
getData("foo", ["fooo"], async () => ["bar"]); // works

getData("foo", ["fooo"], async () => "bar"); // error

// also works because T is not constrained to be non-array
getData("foo", "fooo", async () => ["bar"]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply I had tried you answer but faced a different issue as the we are following strict noExplicitAny policy for the function parameters.

Updated the question with the function declarations and the issue I got into.